# Box equipment while travelling

Tags: cardio, heart-rate

Working the heavy bag at the gym I burn a lot of calories. However, when travelling, which is a considerable part of my life, I won't be able to bring one with me due to A) Weight B) opportunity to hang it.

What equivalent equipment should I carry to substitute it? I expect that it fits in any flying luggage allowance. That is, it should not weight more than 10 pounds (and that's already a lot).

Could a water punching bag be of any use if you can't hang it? I was thinking about a kind of mixed exercise, lifting the bag and punching (hooks and jabs) it a couple of times in the air.

Answer (score 1):

Some punching equipment, like a square punching pad with elastics, can be attached to a door frame.

Having access to a door frame, you can also get creative and attach a double end bag to it. For example, use a pull-up bar as the attachment point for the upper cord and a water-filled base for the bottom cord. The pull-up bar is also a device that's highly portable, and excellent for body weight exercises. Add push-ups and some squats (maybe with some water weight) to it and you have a good workout with portable equipment.

Not really asked, but possibly useful: for getting fit with minimal equipment also search for 'prisoner workout' or 'convict conditioning' literature and media.